# How do I transfer cookie information from google analytics to public dmp?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I really need to know how to transfer cookie information from google analytics (UA or GA4 it doens't matter) to publick dmp.

Actually, is it possible way to moving or copying cookie information from google analytics to other platform? If it is possible, please let me share with your technical specialized knowledge.

I really want to use audiences who are visited in my website for target audience of my public dmp.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

GA's cookies are first party cookies containing an ID which "identifies" the user/browser on/for your domain. You cannot leverage them for you DMP.

If you want to move/copy them, you'll need to wait for the user/browser to revisit your website and then copy their ID to your DMP's cookie or write your DMP's userID as a custom (user scope) dimension into GA. This way you can create a link/mapping between your data.